# how to create a popover when someone move cursor over button in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here I am having two status button, one green color which returns RUNNING and second button red color which returns TERMINATED from JASON.

When moving cursor over status button green color it hover "RUNNING". Tried to get hover on button it does show nothing.

Here is the screen which is required:

[image]

[image]

Here is the code which i have tried:

```
  <button type="button" class="btn {{.Status | statusButtonClass}} btn-circle" 
  data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="hello" data- 
  trigger="hover"> 

<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
</button>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    placement : 'right'
});
});
</script>



.btn-circle{
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
text-align: center;
padding: 6px 0;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 1.428571429;
border-radius: 15px;
}
```

I am currently using Bootstrap 4 version.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you can go through this URL `https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/` hope it helps you out.

Comment: _“it does show nothing”_ - start by checking your browser console for script errors ...

Comment: this seems really inefficient, why not use `.on('hover')` and `removeClass('hidden')` ?

Comment: @AnmolSandal i have tried that already it does not show up anything

Answer (score 1):

It's called **tooltip** what you are trying to get. If you are using bootstrap it is very easy just check this link [Bootstrap tooltips](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/).

And as per your code, you can do is change function in

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
        placement : 'right'
    });
});
</script>
```

And change code to this,

```
<button type="button" class="btn {{.Status | statusButtonClass}} btn-circle" 
  data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Running"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
</button>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    placement: 'right'
  });
});
```

```css
.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-circle" 
  data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Running"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: nothing works..

Comment: You are using bootstrap?

Comment: yes bootstrap 4 .  ....  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="../static/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>

Comment: if i use your above link and script then bootstrap changing the design <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: try my updated answer. And comment if not working this also.

Comment: yeah sure!!!!!!

Comment: and tooltip does not showing

Comment: No problem in console. Check my updated answer. I am sure this will work.

Comment: Thanks it  works fine but my design are changed, when this link used <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: change it to yours as before it will work also with bootstrap 4

Comment: @PvDev It's working or not?

Comment: nope..I think there is problem link and script..

Comment: now show your console

Comment: Hey check question i have added link and script url .. Any missed out there .. let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170851/discussion-between-chirag-patel-and-pvdev).

Answer (score 0):

hi There you can use custom tool tip instead of using your code you can do that with before and after elements .

the tool tip would be a very nice choice to do this thing.and if you want me to create the code for that please let me know.

I will give you some ideas to create them

Comment: do you any sample code

Answer (score 0):

Can you check which version of bootstrap you use? Your code is written for Bootstrap 4 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/. If you want to use Bootstrap 4 simply connect js and css described here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/.

**Sample Code:** https://www.codeply.com/go/mdL9E4yF5b

Answer (score 0):

missing to include some js?
This is your revisited code working:[image]

Comment: nothing works ..

Comment: check your browser console for script errors as suggested by @CBroe

Comment: can you add your code snippet

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/oveJ8UbpV0wtxEqu5Vlg?p=preview